# How to split a string containing a substring in it , using Perl?

Tags: perl, split

I have a string like this

```
"Name : somedata,123 Name : somedata1,234 Name :somedata3,345"
```

I need to split the data to the next line where ever `"Name "` occurs,

I need the final output like this :

```
Name :somedata,123
Name :somedata1,234
Name :somedata3,345
```

Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: How about using [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)?

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for `split` in Perl?  The function is literally named `split`.  http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html

Comment: I tried using split but its giving some errors all the time, may be the code is not correct. Split works well for ',' or '.' but for string i am not able to use it.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code then?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also solve this using [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) and a [`positive lookahead assertion`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns):

```
$string = "Name : somedata,123 Name : somedata1,234 Name :somedata3,345";

my @strings = split /(?=Name)/, $string;

print "<$_>\n" for @strings;
```

Outputs:

```
<Name : somedata,123 >
<Name : somedata1,234 >
<Name :somedata3,345>
```

Note, if the pattern is of zero width, then split will not match at the beginning of a string.  For this reason, we do not need the positive look behind assertion to ensure that we aren't at the start.

Also, if we wanted to get rid of the trailing spaces, we could do that in the split as well:

```
my @strings = split /\s*(?=Name)/, $string;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use substitution with a look-behind and look-ahead: if there is a position preceded by anything (i.e. not the very beginning) followed by `Name`, you insert a newline:

```
my $string = "Name : somedata,123 Name : somedata1,234 Name :somedata3,345";
$string =~ s/(?<=.)(?=Name)/\n/g;
```

Comment: Not sure i am using this properly or not, but the result is the same after using this as well... I tried several times but couldnt figure it out.